# How to rebuild pruned data after prune-state?

Tags: go-ethereum

Geth version 1.10.4 introduced a new feature prune-state

It deletes all state from db except HEAD - 127

What happens if I try to retreive old data via jsonrpc after pruning?

Can I rebuild the pruned data from snapshot? If it is possible how to do it?

---

7/2 edit my question

I removed all state (not ancient) using removedb command and tried
jsonrpc to pull old data, it worked well. So I guess state is just used for syncing.

I have 2 questions about this.

1. Im guessing state is just used for syncing. Am I right?
2. Removedb can remove all state without delay, then why prune-state command exists for the same behavior taking few more hours?

Answer (score 0):

1. It is normal that you can still get data since only states have been pruned (I do not know exactly which data you tried to get with JSON-RPC but if it's transaction for instance, you still have them stored)
2. Pruning is not only about deleting old states, it specifically runs an algorithm to identify which trie nodes can be deleted (it does not take that much time though). What can be long is the database compacting as explained in Geth documentation https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/pruning:

> There may be a period of >1 hour during the Compacting Database stage with no log messages at all. This is normal, and the pruning should be left to run until finally a log message containing the phrase State pruning successful appears (i.e. do not restart Geth yet!). That message indicates that the pruning is complete and Geth can be started.

Hope it helps !